# Use the same button in different interfaces (JAVA)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, popupmenu

I am making a java app for purchasing products, with login and such.
In all the interfaces that I have there is a button that is the "Account" button to log in and if you are already logged in it shows a popUpMenu with different options. My problem is that when trying to use this same button in a different interface, if the user has already logged in and clicks the button I get an error that says it cannot show the popUpMenu because the original button (the one on the main interface) is hidden.

Desde la "InterfazCesta" he usado esto (botonCuenta = InterfazPrincipal.getInstancia().botonCuenta;) para que mi "botonCuenta" obtenga todas las propiedas del original.
Pero al intentar mostrar el popUpMenu me salta este error (porque el boton principal esta oculto):

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: component must be showing on the screen to determine its location
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen_NoTreeLock(Component.java:2113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen(Component.java:2087)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JPopupMenu.show(JPopupMenu.java:982)
    at InterfazProducto.botonCuentaActionPerformed(InterfazProducto.java:766)
    at InterfazProducto$5.actionPerformed(InterfazProducto.java:253)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2314)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:407)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6621)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3398)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6386)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4996)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4828)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4828)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:775)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:98)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

[image]
[image]

These images are of the Main Interface, and it is what I want to do in the rest of the Interfaces.

Comment: You might want to show your pertinent [mre] code in your question as code formatted text. Please read the link to know what I am referring to. You also will probably want to read the [tour] and [ask] links as well. If you have any questions about creating your own MRE or want to know how it can help both you and us, please comment below.

Comment: You are likely not using the "same button", or else some other issue is causing your code to not display the button that you *think* it's displaying, again, an issue in code not shown. You can also find links to similar questions with this Google search: [site:stackoverflow.com java swing popup menu IllegalComponentStateException: component must be showing on the screen to determine its location](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+swing+popup+menu+IllegalComponentStateException%3A+component+must+be+showing+on+the+screen+to+determine+its+location)

Comment: Also, please change your Spanish text to English, since this site is English-only.

Comment: You logic to show the popup should NOT reference a specific component. Instead you should be using the `getSource()` method from your event to access the component that generated the event.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.